# access to array defined in Master View Controller from Detail View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have a master detail Application in xCode.
In Master View Controller an Array is defined.
In Detail View Controller there are detail Informations according to one entry from this array.

Is it possible to get access from Detail View Controller to the array and update them?

How can I pass the reference to the array from the Master View Controller to the Detail View Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a property in your detail controller to hold the array.  Then pass the array reference in whatever method you use now for passing the single entry, either didSelectRowAtIndexPath: for a xib-based app or prepareForSegue: if you have a storyboard.

Comment: property array is already defined in detail veiw controller. I use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath for Ipad: <br> <code> self.detailViewController.detailItem = [self.Array objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

Comment: OK...then what's the actual problem with something like `detailController.array = self.masterArray;` in whichever method matches your app structure?

Comment: I need to modify the entries from array in detail view controller and pass the changes back to master view controller. Can I use some delegates to access to the array defined in master from detail?

Comment: If you have a reference to the array in detail, you should be able to make your changes and have them available in master without passing anything.  There would only be one actual array that's referenced from two view controllers.

Comment: how can I implement the reference in master detail application?

Comment: You said, "property array is already defined in detail veiw controller".  So, just set that property the same way you set `self.detailViewController.detailItem` but use `self.Array` rather than a specific object.

Comment: self.detailViewController.Array = self.Array; <br/> but the Array isn't visible in detail view controller

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "isn't visible".  Please update your question with actual code if you want to pursue this.

Comment: The NSMutableArray Array is defined in MasterViewController, there are some entries. The same NSMutableArray Array is also defined als property in DetailViewController. In MasterViewController in the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath there is following call:         self.detailViewController.Array = self.Array; In DetailViewcontroller the self.Array is empty.